# Debugging and start without debugging options are not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a C# file with the following steps:

```
File -> New -> New File -> C# class
```

But at the time of compilation I noticed that debugging and start without debugging options are not visible.

I have tried the compilation on command line. It is working fine. I want to compile it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you please share command used to compile single C# file?

Comment: In Visual Studio, you debug _Projects_, not _Files_. When you compile a single file with `csc`, you are very likely specifying a _target_

Comment: @GuruStron command used to compile - csc filename.cs

Comment: Nica, have never new that you can compile single file with `Main` (or top-level statement). Though it is rarely useful in real-life development scenarios - create a solution in VS, add project of corresponding type and add your cs file there.

Comment: That's only because `exe` is the default `target`. Type `csc /?` at the command line, and you will see something like `-target:exe - Build a console executable (default) (Short form: -t:exe)` | `-target:winexe - Build a Windows executable (Short form: -t:winexe)` | `-target:library - Build a library (Short form: -t:library)`.  You aren't building that one .CS file, you are building an EXE that contains that file.  For what it's worth, it seems my memory is good.  I learned this in the fall of 2000, before Visual Studio .NET shipped.  I'm not sure if I've used it since then

Comment: @DurveshDineshBodkar You can take a look of my answer. Let me know whether it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your situation:

[image]

This issue comes from your code is not be recognized as Project/Solution.

C# is different from the language like python, open the script file directly will not make it be able to debug/run.

So the solution is creating a minimal structure.

You can follow the below steps to start a demo C# code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the above steps, you will be able to debug the C# code:

[image]